# Which is the modern front end to use for screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

Looking for something that SHOWS opens screens and allows reattachment.

Just one of many examples:

```
root@helium:~# screen -r
There are screens on:
    32159.pts-1.helium  (08/15/2013 03:11:54 PM)    (Attached)
    27669.pts-1.helium  (08/15/2013 02:21:32 PM)    (Attached)
There is no screen to be resumed.
root@helium:~# screen -r 321
There is a screen on:
    32159.pts-1.helium  (08/15/2013 03:11:55 PM)    (Attached)
There is no screen to be resumed matching 321.
root@helium:~# screen -r 32159
There is a screen on:
    32159.pts-1.helium  (08/15/2013 03:11:55 PM)    (Attached)
There is no screen to be resumed matching 32159.
root@helium:~# screen -r 32159.pts-1.helium
There is a screen on:
    32159.pts-1.helium  (08/15/2013 03:11:54 PM)    (Attached)
There is no screen to be resumed matching 32159.pts-1.helium.
root@helium:~# screen REATTACH TO MY GODDAMN SESSION
```

Answer (score 3):

GNU `screen` has two separate commands for "resuming" a session or "attaching" to it. Since it currently thinks your session is *already attached*, you need to do one of two things:

- a) detach the currently-attached terminal using `screen -D`, *then* try `screen -r` again;
- b) use the "multi attach" command `screen -x`.

If you're looking for an *alternative* to `screen`, try **`tmux`**, which always allows attaching multiple times (using the `tmux attach` command).